# Convert HTML special characters in a string

Tags: objective-c, encoding, html-parsing

Through a JSON parser from Google, I get a string. But it contains all the special characters in html format, such as `&#39;` instead of `'`.

Do you know if there is a special encoding, or some method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Google Toolbox for Mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/), specifically the [GTMNSString+HTML](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString%2BHTML.h) category. `- (NSString *)gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML;` is what you need.

Comment: Sure it does. We use this category in our ARC project. Just make sure to have the Google Toolkit files not have ARC (by default, drag+drop into project is ARC).

Comment: Let me know if you need some help.

Comment: thank you, I insert the two files in the project, go to "build phases" and on the file "GTMNSString + HTML.m" insert the flag "-fno-objc-arc". import the class #import "GTMNSString HTML.m +" in my viewcontroller.m, but I still have 4 errors related to ARC

Comment: What are the errors? Are you sure they are related to ARC? I think there were some Google dependencies which need to be removed from the .m file.

Comment: on  NSString *escapeSequence;  there is ARC forbids Objective-C objects in structs or unions...
on  const unichar *buffer = CFStringGetCharactersPtr((CFStringRef)self); there is Cast of Objective-C pointer type 'NSString *' to C pointer type 'CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString *') requires a bridged cast,  the other two are like this

Comment: Wait, in your `#import`, did you import the `.h` file or `.m`? You should import the `.h` file.

Comment: ok thanks, now the errors are 2: `Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "__GTMDevAssert", referenced from:
      -[NSString(GTMNSStringHTMLAdditions) gtm_stringByEscapingHTMLUsingTable:ofSize:escapingUnicode:] in GTMNSString+HTML.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`